# news: wrong link to detail page, ok after clearing fe cache

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I use tx_news 4.3.0 with TYPO3 7.6.12 and realurl 2.0.15

From time to time i get detail links which show to a wrong detail page.

e.g.
`veranstaltungen/talks/detail/xy-talks/`

shows to another detail page:

`veranstaltungen/talks/detail/z-talks/`

after clearing the fe cache the link ist ok.

how to avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem some time ago.

I use for many TYPO3 system a single page for news list and detail.
I wanted to have URLs like example.com/news/ für list view and example.com/news/this-is-a-news/ as detail URL.

To archive this, I configured realurl to skip controller and action for news links. But in the link configuration inside the news template, they were used to build the link.

Since realurl does not create a new cHash for a link (since Version 2.0.12 I think), the link generated by realurl does not match the cHash that was generated in TYPO3 and cached by realurl. So TYPO3 provides a wrong cached version of this page. I my case, it was the first news entry, that were called and cached. This news entry got displayed every time I clicked on a news.

To avoid this, I removed the controller and action skipping from realurl and add some TypoScript (link.skipControllerAndAction = 1) to my news configuration.

I think you might have a similar issue. Try to disable realurl in a dev environment and try if this happens again. When this fixes your problem, check your realurl configuration for news.

Comment: I also have switched back to dedicated list- and detail pages after some painful experiences with mixed list/detail in a custom extbase extension. After some time, the list page realURL would point to some detail page. The separate detail page is a robust solution.